# Apple mach-O link errors everywhere

Tags: ios, sockets

I'm trying to use socket.io on my app and I'm using the pkyeck socket.io implementation. However when i import the files from the pkyeck socket.io and the files from socketrocket, I get 21 Apple mach-O link errors which I have no idea what it means or referring to.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CFHTTPMessageAppendBytes", referenced from:
      ___30-[SRWebSocket _readHTTPHeader]_block_invoke in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields", referenced from:
      ___30-[SRWebSocket _readHTTPHeader]_block_invoke in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket _checkHandshake:] in SRWebSocket.o
      -[SRWebSocket _HTTPHeadersDidFinish] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket didConnect] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket _readHTTPHeader] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket didConnect] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageGetResponseStatusCode", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket _HTTPHeadersDidFinish] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageIsHeaderComplete", referenced from:
      ___30-[SRWebSocket _readHTTPHeader]_block_invoke in SRWebSocket.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket didConnect] in SRWebSocket.o
      ___25-[SRWebSocket didConnect]_block_invoke in SRWebSocket.o
  "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket stream:handleEvent:] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket didConnect] in SRWebSocket.o
      -[SRWebSocket _sendFrameWithOpcode:data:] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket stream:handleEvent:] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateCount", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket stream:handleEvent:] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_kCFHTTPVersion1_1", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket didConnect] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket stream:handleEvent:] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket _initializeStreams] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket _initializeStreams] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
      -[SRWebSocket didConnect] in SRWebSocket.o
      -[SRWebSocket _sendFrameWithOpcode:data:] in SRWebSocket.o
  "_utf8_countTrailBytes", referenced from:
      _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in SRWebSocket.o
  "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
      _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in SRWebSocket.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't really know why I'm getting them as all I did was import the files to the project.

Comment: You are not linking with the required libraries.  You need Security.framework and CoreServices.framework linked in your project.

Comment: @borrrden: You are awesome! Thanks for the correct answer, wish I could have given you more karma